# Logical error in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I have been writing a bash script that calculates a *False Rejection Rate* between the values of two files. Both of the files *file1.txt* and *file2.txt* contain binary values.  All the errors have been fixed, yet the output is **0**. I wonder if I have made any mistake in my script unknowingly as I am very new in writing shell scripts and haven't mastered them yet.

```
#!/bin/bash
nfr=0
ns=0
frr=0

while read file1 <&3 && read file2 <&4; do
    if [$file1 == "1" ]
    then
       let "ns++"
    fi

    if [ "$file1" == "1" ] && [ "$file2" != "1" ]
    then
       let "nfr++"
    else
       continue
    fi
done 3< ./file1.txt 4< ./file2.txt

let frr="((nfr / ns) * 100)"
echo $frr
```

**file1.txt**:

```
2
2
2
2
1
1
1
1
1
2
1
1
2
2
```

**file2.txt**:

```
2
2
2
2
2
2
1
1
1
2
1
1
2
2
```

Comment: The code as posted contains trivial syntax errors.  Please check with http://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human debugging help.

Comment: While I'm sure it's possible to do this in a shell script, it must be easier in something like python or perl?

Comment: `paste file1.txt file2.txt | awk '$1 == 1 { ns++ } $1 == 1 && $2 != 1 { nfr++ } END { print 100*(nfr/ns) }'`

Comment: Note that Bash does not do floating point arithmetic (whereas Korn shell does).  At minimum, you should multiply by 100 before dividing.

Comment: The `else continue` part is useless.

Comment: Thank you for all the valuable suggestions.

Comment: Thank that I have found out where my fault was.
`let frr=$(bc <<<100*$nfr/$ns)`

works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that the shell uses integer arithmetic, so your division will always be truncated to zero.

Your script has a syntax error (no space after a `[`), and it does not double quote the variable references in the `[` … `]` expression which will lead to syntax errors if there is an empty line in the input file.

You can use `dc` for arbitrary precision arithmetic if installed.

Here is my version:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i nfr=0
declare -i ns=0

while read file1 <&3 && read file2 <&4; do
    if [ "$file1" == "1" ]
    then
        let "ns++"

        if [ "$file2" != "1" ]
        then
            let "nfr++"
        fi
    fi
done 3< ./file1.txt 4< ./file2.txt

# this will remove the decimal fraction
echo $((nfr * 100 / ns))
# this will print the value with a precision of 5
precision=5
echo "$precision k$nfr $ns/100*p" | dc
```